# Prove that an automorphism group is a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, let $T$ be an automorphism of $G$, and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that $T(N)=\{T(x) \mid x\in N\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I would prefer a hint to get started, rather than a full solution.

Comment: You know that $xNx^{-1}=N$ for all $x\in G$. what can you say about $xT(N)x^{-1}$?

Comment: You don't need $T$ to be injective, just surjective.

Comment: In general, the image of a normal subgroup under a homomorphism is a normal subgroup of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since $T$ is an automorphism, for any $g\in G$, there is some $h$ with $T(h)=g$.  Then

$$gT(x)g^{-1}=\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the title is not compatible with the question.

Although, you can prove that the image of $N$ by any surjective homomorphism is normal, take $g \in G$ and write it as a image of some other element by your surjection, next use the definition of a group homomorphism, what happen?